# Call the custom function which outside plugin and pass parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, arguments

I want to Try to call a function outside my plugin, that the function is pass by the "options" of plugin. The function can be called, but my code fail to pass the parameters defined inside my plugin.

How to pass those parameters from inside to the public scope?

---

```
$(document).myPlugin({
     afterDone : function(){testingCall()}
});

function testingCall(){
    alert(arguments[0]);
    alert(arguments[1]);
}
```

---

```
(function($){  

var MyPlugin = function(element, options){
    var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin, options||{});
    /* ------ Do somthing, whatever  -----*/

    //call the custom function here
    settings.afterDone('para01','para02');

};

$.fn.myPlugin =  function(options){
    return this.each(function(key, value){
        new MyPlugin(this, options);
    });
};

$.fn.myPlugin.defaults = {
    afterDone : function(){}
};

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
$(document).myPlugin({
    afterDone : function(){testingCall()}
});
```

to:

```
$(document).myPlugin({
    afterDone: function () {
        testingCall.apply(null, arguments);
    }
});
```

This will call `testingCall` and pass in the original argument list that was passed to `afterDone`. I passed `null` for the first argument of `apply` as I was unsure of which context you wanted to use for `this`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TGG2J/

**UPDATE**

If the user of your plugin does not know beforehand which arguments you are adding to `afterDone` by default and they want to pass in those arguments to `testingCall` they would have to define `afterDone` like this:

```
$(document).myPlugin({
    afterDone: function () {
        var userArgs = ['user01', 'user02'],
            i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 1) {
            // to make your arguments the first arguments, do this
            userArgs.splice(0 + i, 0, arguments[i]);
            // to make the user's arguments the first arguments, do this
            //userArgs.push(arguments[i]);
        }
        testingCall.apply(null, userArgs);
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TGG2J/1/

But that will likely be confusing, especially to new JavaScripters. It might make more sense to let the user know (in documentation) that that you are pre-supplying two arguments to `afterDone` so that the they can use them at their discretion:

```
$(document).myPlugin({
    afterDone: function (p1, p2) {
        testingCall(p1, p2, 'myArgs');
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TGG2J/2/

While (to my knowledge) nothing can be done by editing anything at the line of:

```
settings.afterDone('para01','para02');
```

specifying the parameters in documentation still allows the user to use them.

Comment: Thank you. But to make it more simply for the user of the plugin, can this be done by edit something at the line of "settings.afterDone('para01','para02');" ?